# How can I use a different background color for every card of my card list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a cardList and I want to use a different color for every card in the cardList. I tried to do it by my self but it became complicated.

Here is the cardList:

```
return (
  <Container>
    <Row className="row gy-4 mt-4">
      {profsData && profsData.data.map((item) => (
        <Col key={item.id} className='col-3'>
          <Card className='h-100 w-100 py-5'>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{item.username}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                {item.bio}
              </Card.Text>
              {item.college && (<h6 className='fw-bold mt-5'>Collège</h6>)}
              {item.lycee && (<h6 className='fw-bold mb-5'>Lycée</h6>)}
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => handleShow(item.id)}>Rendez-Vous</Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      ))}
    </Row>
  </Container>
)
```

and here is the array of color with the function selecting randomly a color:

```
const variant = [
  'Primary',
  'Secondary',
  'Success',
  'Danger',
  'Warning',
  'Info',
  'Light',
  'Dark',
]

const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * variant.length)
const colorPicked = variant[index]
```

I'm using a `map()` function to display the data in the profsData array and I can't use another `map()` for the variant array inside the first `map()` function.

Comment: @nbjorling, answers go down there. You short-circuit the process when you post them as comments.

Comment: Sorry about that and thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pseudo-random color then compute a random color for each card that is mapped.

```
return (
  <Container>
    <Row className="row gy-4 mt-4">
      {profsData?.data.map((item) => {
        const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * variant.length)
        const randomVariant = variant[randIndex];

        return (
          <Col key={item.id} className='col-3'>
            ... use randomVariant in JSX ...
          </Col>
        );
      })}
    </Row>
  </Container>
);
```

If you just want a different color per card then use the mapped data index and select a variant color. Taking the modulus of the mapped index by `variant` array length ensures a valid index within the array.

```
return (
  <Container>
    <Row className="row gy-4 mt-4">
      {profsData?.data.map((item, index) => {
        const selectedVariant = variant[index % variant.length];

        return (
          <Col key={item.id} className='col-3'>
            ... use selectedVariant in JSX ...
          </Col>
        );
      })}
    </Row>
  </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const variant = [
    'Primary',
    'Secondary',
    'Success',
    'Danger',
    'Warning',
    'Info',
    'Light',
    'Dark',
  ]    
{profsData && profsData.data.map((item,index) => (
          <Col key={item.id} className='col-3'>
            <Card variant={variant[index] ? variant[index] : variant[0]} className='h-100 w-100 py-5'>
              ...
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        ))}
```

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation. See [answer].